# how to stop script from duplicating events in calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm using google form to autofill a google sheet. With this form, clients can tell me when they wanna make a reservation. I used some code to sync my google sheet to google calendar.

I have 2 problems.

(1) each time I run the script, it duplicates the event. 
(2) when theres more rows added, it doesn't sync the new events since I preselected the range. (It's the only way I know) I can't be modifying my code everytime a new row is added!

here is the code so far:

```
function scheduleShifts() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("P1").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("J2:L4").getValues();

for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

var shift = signups [x];

var startTime = shift[0];
var endTime = shift[1];
var inspector = shift[2];


eventCal.createEvent(inspector, startTime, endTime);
}
}

function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Synchroniser au calendrier')
   .addItem('Sync now', 'scheduleShifts')
   .addToUi();

}
```

Comment: Why not just delete the rows in the spreadsheet as you create events in your calendar.

Comment: @Cooper didnt thought of that... it could work..

Comment: I would be helpful if we could see a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: I would consider not even adding the event to the spreadsheet. Just create the event with a dialog.  You can always get a list of the events over a date range directly from the Calendar.

Comment: https://ibb.co/984dKwB @Cooper sample

Comment: What's a dialog? Maybe if I tell you more about how we work it might help you help me! Clients have our google form, they fill it, we receive it trough google sheets. Now we have to negociate with them the availability of our services. Then, when we both agree on a time, we write down the start/end time and sync it to google calendar... Do you think theres a more efficient way to work? Sorry for my english btw im french! @Cooper

Comment: You can build a dialog with the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) that accepts the  three datas of inspector, startTime and endTime and then it calls a google apps script function via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) that creates an event in the calendar.  If you want to know what events were create d and by which inspectors you can write separate functions that retrieve the information from the calendar.  Or if you wish you can also store them into a local spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a dialog that is probably close to what you could use.

File Name: aq4.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
        var id='sel1';
        var select = document.getElementById(id);
        select.options.length = 0; 
        for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getInspectors();
    });
      function submitForm(frmData) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
          document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=hl;
        })
        .createEvent(frmData)
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Event Dialog</h1>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <br /><input type="text" name="title" value=""/> Title
        <br /><input type="datetime-local" name="start" id="dt"/> Start
        <br /><input type="datetime-local" name="end" /> End
        <br /><select id="sel1" name="inspector"></select> Inspector
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

File Name: aq1.gs

```
function createEvent(frmData) {
  //Logger.log('title: %s, start: %s, end: %s, inspector: %s ',frmData.title,frmData.start,frmData.end,frmData.inspector);
  var rv='Event Not Created';
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendar id");//insert your calendar id
  var event=cal.createEvent(frmData.title,new Date(frmData.start),new Date(frmData.end));
  if(event) {
    event.setDescription(Utilities.formatString('Inspector: %s', frmData.inspector))
    rv="Event Created";
  }
  return rv;
}


//The following function gets the data in column one of the Inspectors sheet or tab in the script container spreadsheet.  You can create your own list that way and then you wont have to type them in 
function getInspectors() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Inspectors');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  return vA;
}

function launchDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq4');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Event Creation Dialog");
}
```

Here's a freebie you can use to display your calendar id's:

```
function displayCalendarInfo()
{
  var cals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s='Calendar Information';
  for(var i=0;i<cals.length;i++)
  {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Name: %s Id: %s', cals[i].getName(),cals[i].getId());
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Calendar Data');
}
```

It's also a simple dialog.

Here's what the  Dialog Looks like:

[image]

> A Warning: Don't try to pass Date()'s from client to server with google.script.run.  Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) until you understand what it is telling you.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I wish I knew how to read this and know where to paste this code in order to see the results. I will try to do something with it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so Much @Cooper !!! Here you go : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_V2kU_YfkuqylcFhRHpSOvCtwXir8l5yC8F4mX3Zrmk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I meant that if you shared a spreadsheet I would setup this example for you but I don't want to integrate it into your current spreadsheet because that can't get complicated and take more time than I have right now.

Comment: Yes, absolutely understandable ! You can use the spreadsheet I sent you, it's not the one im using right now it's just a test !! Do whatever you want with it !

Comment: This link `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_V2kU_YfkuqylcFhRHpSOvCtwXir8l5yC8F4mX3Zrmk/edit?usp=sharing` is view only.

Comment: what have you done exactly? What am I suppose to see?

Comment: I haven’t done anything because that link is view only and I can’t access the script editor in order to set up the Scripts. I simply volunteered to set up the Scripts to get that example working for you so that you can see it and then perhaps learn how to modify it to your own needs.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_V2kU_YfkuqylcFhRHpSOvCtwXir8l5yC8F4mX3Zrmk/edit?usp=sharing  It should work now !!!! sorry !

Comment: Okay.  So now you run a function like displayCalendarInfo() so that you can authorize the code.  I think I actually pasted the correct calendarId in there already but you might want to check that.  It just createds a form that allows you to enter some data including a date and time and then it will create an event in the calendar with the given id.  You can run launchDialog() to the the dialog running.

Answer (score 0):

### An easy solution based in your code would be the following:

1. To avoid duplicating events

   - retrieve all events of a calendar with [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)
   - [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) their titles into an array
   - Verify with [IndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) either an event to be created already exists

```
var existingEvents=Calendar.Events.list(calendarId);
var eventArray=[]; 
existingEvents.items.forEach(function(e){eventArray.push(e.summary)});                                                    
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
  var shift = signups [x];
  var startTime = shift[0];
  var endTime = shift[1];
  var inspector = shift[2];
    if(eventArray.indexOf(inspector)==-1){ 
      eventCal.createEvent(inspector, startTime, endTime);
    }else{
      Logger.log('event exists already');
    }
  }
```

> Make sure to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) Advanced Calendar Service before usage

2. To dynamically detect all rows in your spreadsheet, use the method [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) and define your range as [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns):

```
var startRow=2;
var startColumn=10; //column J
var rowNumber=spreadsheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1;
var columnNumber=3;
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,rowNumber,columnNumber).getValues();
```